# How to populate UIImage in UITableViewCell using JSON containing data of a bytea field (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am populating an `UITableView` using data returned in **JSON** by a webservice with a PostgreSQL backend. The thumbnail image data is stored as `bytea` in the database.

The data returned by the JSON field 'thumbnail' (`recentRiddims[indexPath.row].thumbnail`) looks something like:              `\xffd8ffe000104a46494600010200000100010000ffdb0043000806060706050807070709 ...`

One can tell it is a *JPEG* image by its magic byte `0xFFD8FF`. However, the string appears to be escaped. In **PHP** I'm usually using `pg_unescape_bytea(data)` to get the actual image data which can be used to display images in browsers. Hence I've tried that with the same set of **JSON** data in **PHP** I know that the data is a valid *JPEG* image.

The app compiles and launches fine but the thumbnail `UIImageView` in the `UITableViewCell` displays empty (a grey box, color of the `UIImageView`'s background), while the `UILabel`s' texts are updated with data from **JSON**.

I'm new to **Swift** so I'm sure there's a simple way of getting this done that I do not know about yet.

the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function looks like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let recentRiddimsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recentRiddimsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecentRiddimsCell
    // Configure the cell...
    recentRiddimsCell.riddimLabel.text = recentRiddims[indexPath.row].riddim
    recentRiddimsCell.labelLabel.text = recentRiddims[indexPath.row].label

    //image test
    var thumbnailString: String! = recentRiddims[indexPath.row].thumbnail

    let imageData = NSData(data: thumbnailString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    recentRiddimsCell.imageThumbnail.image = image

    return recentRiddimsCell
}
```

`recentRiddims` is an array of tuples `[(riddim: String, label: String, count: String, thumbnail: String)]`, containing the parsed **JSON** values for each key.

I assume the thumbnail does not show the image because the data is escaped.

Is there an equivalent of **PHP**'s `pg_unescape_bytea()` or is the user supposed to unescape manually? (I'm not really sure how to manually unescape though.)

Is there an easier way of populating the `UITableView` via JSON data in swift?

The project's deployment target is set to *iOS 8.4* using *Universal*, running latest XCode on Yosemite.

**EDIT:** 
I no longer think the **JSON** data for key "thumbnail" is in escaped format, I just had a look into the database where the data is stored like `\377\330\377\340\000\020JFIF\000\001\002\000\000\001\000 ...`. Apparently the conversion from `\oct` is done by the **PHP** webservice, though, I don't know why the thumbnail data begins with `\x`. I rather expected it to start with `ffd8ff...` or `0xffd8ff...`. If the **JSON** data holds properly escaped bytea data, why does the app not show the thumbnail image at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night of sleep that removed my brain-stall I instantly realized my mistake by looking at the code with a fresh mind; the data is valid image data encoded in hex, prepended by `\x`.

All I had to do was removing `\x` from the `String` object, using `(thumbnailString as NSString).substringFromIndex(2)` and then `NSData.fromHexString(thumbnailString)`, to decode the hex string and create a `NSData` object from it.

The `extension` for `NSData` can be found [here](https://github.com/CryptoCoinSwift/RIPEMD-Swift/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BHexString.swift), credits go to *Sjors Provoost*.